# Icon should have `type` prop or `component` prop or `children`?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
Warning: Icon should have `type` prop or `component` prop or `children`. 
How to troubleshoot the issue？

import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators,createStore } from 'redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import actions from '../../actions/information/inforResource.js';
import Dropdown from '../../components/common/dropdown.js';
import ListSearch from '../../components/common/listSearch.js';
import moment from 'moment';
import {Modal, Icon, Button, Row, Col, Form, DatePicker, Select, Table, Input, Pagination, Menu, Tooltip, Drawer, message, Avatar} from 'antd';

<Icon type="delete"/>
```

I deleted the icon tags of the page and still reported an error.
I deleted the Icon tag in the subcomponent and still reported an error.

```
react.development.js?99ee:335 
Warning: Icon should have `type` prop or 
`component` prop or `children`.
printWarning       warning.js?bcd6:34
warning            warning.js?bcd6:57
_default           warning.js?fe52:16
Icon               index.js?be01:80
renderWithHooks    react-dom.development.js?cada:12938
mountIndeterminateComponent  react-dom.development.js?cada:15020
beginWork          react-dom.development.js?cada:15625
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same error but with react-native instead? if you are using react-native use this package instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ant-design/icons-react-native

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is to import icon directly.**

import -

```
import DeleteOutlined from '@ant-design/icons/DeleteOutlined';
```

call -

```
<DeleteOutlined />
```

'antd' version in `package.json` -

```
"dependencies": {
    @ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "antd": "^4.19.5",
}
```